# I can't apply jalali moment date format to devextreme header filter display data

Tags: angular, datagrid, devexpress, devextreme, jetbrains-rider

I can't customize display data in headerfilter.

Hi, I set the value of the column related to the date as solar using the jalali moment library, and when the page is loaded, it is displayed correctly.
But when I open the popup related to HeaderFilter, instead of displaying the jalali momemnt format, it displays the format stored in the database.

I will be grateful if a friend can guide me to display the date in the Jalali moment format in the header filter.

Tip, remote operation is on.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!